# Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver

Tags: android-emulator, avd-manager, intel-haxm

I am using android studio 2.2.3. I am trying to run an avd. Whenever i run it, it gives me warning that intel haxm is deprecated and to switch to android emulator hypervisor driver(aehd). I have installed aehd but the avd is not using it i guess. I still get the warning that aehd is deprecated. What should i do?

Comment: As you are using a very old version of Android studio (about 8 years old). Is that a mistake or is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: No reason. Just that i installed this version about 6 years ago, used for some time then stopped using it until now. The project is also very old

Comment: Are you sure aehd is correctly installed. Execute `sc.exe query aehd` (assuming you are on Windows) and check the result.  See also https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-aehd